# Where is the error? Expectation, independent random variables

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Let $X,Z$ be two correlated variables and $Y,Z\sim N(0,1)$ where Y is independent of $X,Z$. Consider the expectation:
$$E[f(X,Y)Z].$$
If $f(X,Y)$ and $Z$ are independent then clearly $E[f(X,Y)Z]=E[f(X,Y)]E[Z]=0$ but I guess this is not in general true since $X$ and $Z$ are correlated. Nevertheless, I can argue as follows, by conditioning on $X$.
\begin{align*}
E[f(X,Y)Z]=& E[E[f(x,Y)Z| X=x]]\\
=&E\left[\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)z e^{-z^2/2} e^{-y^2/2} dzdy \bigg|_{X=x}\right]\\
=& E\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) e^{-y^2/2} dy \underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty  z e^{-z^2/2}  dz}_{=0} \bigg|_{X=x}\right]\\
=& 0.
\end{align*}

I really wonder where the error is! Could anyone help me? :)
Thank you very much!

Comment: If $X=Z$ and $f(x,y) = x$ then $E[f(X,Y)Z] = E[Z^2] = 1$.  Try seeing which step of your argument is incorrect in this case.

Comment: Yes, it must be before the third equality, but the first one seems OK to me... and $Y$ and $Z$ are independent so the joint density should be the product of densities... So I really don't know :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner expectation in the expression $E[E(f(x,Y)Z| X=x)]$, namely $E[f(x,Y)Z| X=x]$ is a conditional expectation. So the density to be used should be the conditional density

$f_{XYZ|X}(x,y,z\mid X=x)$, and *not* the joint density $f_{YZ}(y,z) = f_Y(y)f_Z(z)$ that you use, even though $X$ is fixed at a specific value. The way you write it, you indeed end up calculating the *unconditional* expected value of $Z$, even though $Z$ is correlated with $X$ and therefore its expected value conditional on $X=x$ is not equal to its unconditional expected value. You arrive at this mistaken result because the way you write the conditioning statement in your integral expression corresponds to

$E[\{E(f(X=x,Y)Z)\}| X=x]$ and not to $E[E(f(x,Y)Z| X=x)]$.

Namely, your integral expression corresponds to taking the conditional expected value (outer) of an unconditional expected value (inner), while in reality you want to calculate the unconditional expected value (outer) of a conditional expected value(inner).

Comment: I think I understand the reasoning, although it's not very intuitive. It seems intuitive that, once having knowledge of $X=x$, then suddenly $f(x,Y)$ and $Z$ are no longer dependent, and thus, $E[f(X=x,Y)Z|X=x]=0$ but OK. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Sure, now I see it clear! Hehe, thanks!